# How to execute a generic target in a C makefile?

Tags: c, makefile

I want to create a Makefile, which compiles each .c file in the the directory to a .o file with the same name.
But for some reason, it does not work. I am not sure if I "call" the generic target properly. Can you help me?

```
CC = clang
CFLAGS = -std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra
.PHONY: clean all

all: *.o

clean:
    rm -f *.o 

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<
```

Greetings

Comment: ... and even in a shell script, `*.o` would expand only to the names of files that already exist.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler that's absolutely wrong. `make` does expand glob in its targets and prerequisites, and does it since its very first version. Example: `touch a.x; touch a.y; make -f <(echo '*.x: *.y; cp "$^" "$@"')`. The problem, as John Bollinger said,  is that `*.o` will only expand to the filenames which already exist.

Comment: To the OP: replace the `all: *.o` rule with `all: *.c; $(MAKE) $(?:.c=.o)`. With GNU make, there may be better solutions than calling  make recursively.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler what is "classic make"? The very first make (from Unix version 7), did support globs in both targets and prerequisites, and so does any make implementation I know of.

Comment: And it was also [documented](https://minnie.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=V7/usr/doc/make): ```(Shell metacharacters ``\(**'' and ``?'' are expanded.)```.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I do not "think" it did that, I've checked and tested it. You can have a look at the source [here](https://minnie.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=V7/usr/src/cmd/make/files.c) -- see the `amatch()` function.

Comment: @user414777 — OK; I've dug out my printed copy of Unix 7th Edition UNIX Programmer's Manual Vol 2, and in the article on `make`, it does indeed say that `*` and `?` are expanded.  My bad.  I've removed my previous comments, and will consider modifying my variant of `make`.  It's a wholly separate discussion whether wildcards are a good idea. I don't like them in this context, but, as I said, it is a separate discussion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others commented, this line:

```
all: *.o
```

expands the right side just to the *existing* files.

You can use these functions to "collect" all C sources, and exchange the extension:

```
all: $(patsubst %.c, %.o, $(wildcard *.c))
```

However, not every make will support these functions.

(Note: Why can't you explicitly list the object files you want generated?)